# No overload for method, takes 0 arguments?

Tags: c#

I have:

```
 public static int[] ArrayWorkings()
```

I can call it happily with MyClass.ArrayWorkings() from anywhere.  But I want to build in some extra functionality by requiring a parameter such as:

```
 public static int[] ArrayWorkings(int variable)
```

I get the error No overload for method ArrayWorkings, takes 0 arguments.  Why is this?

Comment: "... by requiring a parameter..."

Comment: You've added a parameter to the method and you are now required to supply a value for it. The compiler is telling you that the parameter is required, just like you wanted it to be, unless I'm misunderstanding

Comment: I thought the error was coming from the method line not where it was being called, never checked stupid waste of your time sorry.

Comment: No problem `:)` sometimes it just takes another set of eyes.

Comment: Can't say I agree with the close reason or the downvote.  Just because a problem seems trivial doesn't make the question invalid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You changed the function to require one parameter... so now all of your old function calls, which passed no parameters, are invalid.

Is this parameter absolutely necessary, or is it a default value?  if it is a default then use a default parameter or an overload:

```
//`variable` will be 0 if called with no parameters
public static int[] ArrayWorkings(int variable=0)  

// pre-C# 4.0
public static int[] ArrayWorkings()
{
    ArrayWorkings(0);
}

public static int[] ArrayWorkings(int variable)
{
    // do stuff
}
```