# No overload for method 'xxxxx' takes 8 arguments

Tags: c#, stack

I'm pretty new at c# so forgive me for the basic question, but how do you fix the problem "No overload for method 'SaveData' takes 8 arguments"?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace Assignment2partA
{
    class Program
    {
        const int MAXCUSTOMERS = 1;
        const float PEAK_RATE = 0.50F;
        const float OFF_PEAK_RATE = 0.18F;
        const float STANDARD_RATE = 0.32F;
        const float GST_RATE = 0.10F;
        const string PEAK_SYM = "P";
        const string STANDARD_SYM = "S";

        static void Main()
        {



            string[] CustomerNumber = new string[MAXCUSTOMERS];
            string[] CustomerName = new string[MAXCUSTOMERS];
            string[] CustomerAddress = new string[MAXCUSTOMERS];
            string[] CustomerRateType = new string[MAXCUSTOMERS];

            float[] Peak = new float[MAXCUSTOMERS];
            float[] OffPeak = new float[MAXCUSTOMERS];
            float[] Standard = new float[MAXCUSTOMERS];

            int currentcustomer = 0;
            string menuSelection = "";


            while (menuSelection != "x")
            {
                menuSelection = Menu();
                switch (menuSelection)
                {
                    case "s":
                        SaveData(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, Standard, ref currentcustomer);
                        break;

                    case "a":
                        AddCustomer(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, Standard, MAXCUSTOMERS, ref currentcustomer);
                        break;

                    case "f":
                        FindCustomer(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, Standard, currentcustomer, CustomerName.ToString());
                        break;

                    case "u":
                        Update(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, Standard, currentcustomer, CustomerName.ToString());
                        break;

                    case "e":
                        Electricity(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, Standard, currentcustomer);
                        break;

                    case "b":
                        Bills(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, Standard, ref currentcustomer);
                        break;




                    case "c":
                        Clear(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, Standard, currentcustomer);
                        break;

                    case "x":
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        static string Menu()
        {
            string menuSelection = "";
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("Add a Customer? (a)");
            Console.WriteLine("Find a Customer? (f)");
            Console.WriteLine("Update a Customer Record? (u)");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Electricity Consumption data? (e)");
            Console.WriteLine("Calculate Bills? (b)");
            Console.WriteLine("Save data to file? (s)");
            Console.WriteLine("Clear Consuption data? (c)");
            Console.WriteLine("Exit? (x)");
            Console.Write("Enter your response >");
            menuSelection = Console.ReadLine();

            return menuSelection;
        }
        static void AddCustomer(string[] CustomerNumber, string[] CustomerName, string[] CustomerAddress, string[] CustomerRateType, float[] Peak, float[] OffPeak, float[] Standard, int MaxCustomers, ref int CurrentCustomer)
        {
            if (CurrentCustomer < MaxCustomers)
            {


                Console.WriteLine("Enter Customer Number");
                Console.Write("Customer Number  > ");
                CustomerNumber[CurrentCustomer] = Console.ReadLine();
                if (CustomerNumber[CurrentCustomer] == "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error : Customer Number cannot be empty,");
                }
                // Get the Customer Name and exit is an error is detected
                Console.Write("Customer Name    > ");
                CustomerName[CurrentCustomer] = Console.ReadLine();
                if (CustomerName[CurrentCustomer] == "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error : Customer Name cannot be empty,");
                }
                // Get the Customer Address and exit is an error is detected
                Console.Write("Address          > ");
                CustomerAddress[CurrentCustomer] = Console.ReadLine();
                if (CustomerAddress[CurrentCustomer] == "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error : Address cannot be empty,");
                }
                // Get the Rate Type and exit is an error is detected
                while (CustomerRateType[CurrentCustomer] != PEAK_SYM && CustomerRateType[CurrentCustomer] != STANDARD_SYM)
                {
                    Console.Write("Standard Rate (S) or Peak/Off Peak (P) >");
                    CustomerRateType[CurrentCustomer] = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                    if (CustomerRateType[CurrentCustomer] != PEAK_SYM && CustomerRateType[CurrentCustomer] != STANDARD_SYM)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error : The Rate Type must be either S or P.");
                    }
                }

            }
          } 
        static int Search(string[] CustomerName, int Count, string id)
        {
            int record;
            for (record = 0; record < Count; record++)
                if (CustomerName[record] == id) break;

            if (record != Count) return -1; // not found
            else return record;                  // return record number
        }
        static void FindCustomer(string[] CustomerNumber, string[] CustomerName, string[] CustomerAddress, string[] CustomerRateType, float[] Peak, float[] OffPeak, float[] Standard, int CurrentCustomer, string CustomerSearch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Customer Name: ");

            CustomerSearch = Console.ReadLine();
            int record = Search(CustomerName, CurrentCustomer, CustomerSearch);

            if (record == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! There is no customer that contains that name. ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CustomerNumber[record]);
                Console.WriteLine(CustomerName[record]);
                Console.WriteLine(CustomerAddress[record]);
                Console.WriteLine(CustomerRateType[record]);

                if (CustomerRateType[record] == PEAK_SYM)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Peak[record]);
                    Console.WriteLine(OffPeak[record]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Standard[record]);
                }

            }
        }

        static void Bills(string[] CustomerNumber, string[] CustomerName, string[] CustomerAddress, string[] CustomerRateType, float[] Peak, float[] OffPeak, float[] Standard, ref int CurrentCustomer)
        {
            float TotalBilled = 0.0F;
            float TotalUsage = 0.0F;
            float AverageBilled = 0.0F;
            float AverageUsage = 0.0F;

            int record;
            CurrentCustomer = CustomerName.Length;

            // Calculation variables
            float PeakCharge = 0.0F;
            float OffPeakCharge = 0.0F;
            float TotalCharge = 0.0F;
            float TotalPlusGST = 0.0F;

            for (record = 0; record < CurrentCustomer; record++)
            {
                if (CustomerRateType[record] == PEAK_SYM)
                {
                    PeakCharge = Peak[record] * PEAK_RATE;
                    OffPeakCharge = OffPeak[record] * OFF_PEAK_RATE;
                    TotalCharge = PeakCharge + OffPeakCharge;
                    // Keep track of the usage
                    TotalUsage = TotalUsage + (Peak[record] + OffPeak[record]);
                }
                else
                {
                    TotalCharge = Standard[record] * STANDARD_RATE;
                    // Keep track of the usage
                    TotalUsage = TotalUsage + Standard[record];
                }

                TotalPlusGST = TotalCharge + TotalCharge * GST_RATE;
                // Keep track of the total billed
                TotalBilled = TotalBilled + TotalPlusGST;

                Console.WriteLine("===================================");
                Console.WriteLine("Electricity Bill for Customer {0}", CustomerNumber[record]);
                Console.WriteLine("===================================");
                Console.WriteLine("Name          : {0}", CustomerName[record]);
                Console.WriteLine("Address       : {0}", CustomerAddress[record]);
                if (CustomerRateType[record] == PEAK_SYM)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Peak          : {0,7:C}", PeakCharge);
                    Console.WriteLine("Off Peak      : {0,7:C}", OffPeakCharge);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Total         : {0,7:C}", TotalCharge);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Including GST : {0,7:C}", TotalPlusGST);
                Console.WriteLine("===================================");
            }
            AverageBilled = TotalBilled / CurrentCustomer;
            AverageUsage = TotalUsage / CurrentCustomer;
            // Display the averages
            Console.WriteLine("Average amount billed is {0:C}.", AverageBilled);
            Console.WriteLine("Average consumption per customer is {0}.", AverageUsage);

        }
        static void Update(string[] CustomerNumber, string[] CustomerName, string[] CustomerAddress, string[] CustomerRateType, float[] Peak, float[] OffPeak, float[] Standard, int CurrentCustomer, string CustomerSearch)
        {
            string Update;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Customer Name: ");

            CustomerSearch = Console.ReadLine();
            int record = Search(CustomerName, CurrentCustomer, CustomerSearch);

            if (record == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! There is no customer that contains that name. ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CustomerNumber[record]);
                Console.Write("Do you want to update this record? (Y/N): ");
                Update = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Update == "Y")
                {
                    Console.Write("Please enter new value: ");
                    CustomerNumber[record] = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(CustomerName[record]);
                Console.Write("Do you want to update this record? (Y/N): ");
                Update = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Update == "Y")
                {
                    Console.Write("Please enter new value: ");
                    CustomerName[record] = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(CustomerAddress[record]);
                Console.Write("Do you want to update this record? (Y/N): ");
                Update = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Update == "Y")
                {
                    Console.Write("Please enter new value: ");
                    CustomerAddress[record] = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(CustomerRateType[record]);

                if (CustomerRateType[record] == PEAK_SYM)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Peak[record]);
                    Console.WriteLine(OffPeak[record]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Standard[record]);

                }
            }
        }
        static void Electricity(string[] CustomerNumber, string[] CustomerName, string[] CustomerAddress, string[] CustomerRateType, float[] Peak, float[] OffPeak, float[] Standard, int CurrentCustomer)
        {
            CurrentCustomer = CustomerName.Length;
            int record;
            for (record = 0; record < CurrentCustomer; record++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CustomerName[record]);

                if (CustomerRateType[record] == PEAK_SYM)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Peak Usage: ");
                    Peak[record] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Off Peak Usage: ");
                    OffPeak[record] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Standard Usage: ");
                    Standard[record] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }



            }
        }




        static void Clear(string[] CustomerNumber, string[] CustomerName, string[] CustomerAddress, string[] CustomerRateType, float[] Peak, float[] OffPeak, float[] Standard, int CurrentCustomer)
        {
            CurrentCustomer = CustomerName.Length;
            int record;
            for (record = 0; record < CurrentCustomer; record++)
            {
                Peak[record] = 0.0f;
                OffPeak[record] = 0.0f;
                Standard[record] = 0.0f;

            }




        }
        static void SaveData(string CustomerNumber, string CustomerName, string CustomerAddress, string CustomerRateType, float Peak, float OffPeak, float Standard)
        {
            FileStream fin;
            string str;
            string[] data = null;
            // Open a file for reading
            try
            {
                fin = new FileStream("billingdata.txt", FileMode.Open);
            }
            // Report an error if file cannot be opened
            catch (IOException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                return;
            }

            StreamReader fstr_in = new StreamReader(fin);
            string str1 = "";
            StreamWriter fstr_out;
            try
            {
                fstr_out = new StreamWriter("billingdata.txt");
            }
            catch (IOException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                fstr_out.WriteLine(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerRateType);
            }
            catch (IOException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                return;
            }
            fstr_out.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When you start passing this many arguments to methods, a strong case can be made for a dedicated class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No overload for method, takes 0 arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217681/no-overload-for-method-takes-0-arguments)

Comment: Please, don't write code like this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the smallest program that demonstrates the problem. Delete all the irrelevant code. Also, say what line the error occurs on. We are not psychic. (To make it even more difficult, you removed the name of the method that was causing the error.) This is like handing somebody a book and saying, "My editor tells me there is a spelling mistake. Can you help me fix it?" Finally, what part of the error message did you not understand? There is no overload that takes 8 arguments. So why are you passing 8 arguments?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to pass **eight** parameters to method `SaveData` that can accept only **seven** you have to `remove` one parameter from call that is not required or **add** one more parameter in method definition.

Method call, trying to pass **eight** parameters,

```
SaveData(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress,
          CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, 
          Standard, ref currentcustomer);
```

Method definition having **seven** parameters.

```
static void SaveData(string CustomerNumber, string CustomerName, string CustomerAddress,     
                     string CustomerRateType, float Peak, float OffPeak, 
                     float Standard)
```

Comment: if i take 'ref currentcustomer' off, i get the following errors:

Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Assignment2partA.Program.SaveData(string, string, string, string, float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments

Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'
Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'
Error 4 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'
Error 5 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'
Error 6 Argument 5: cannot convert from 'float[]' to 'float'

Comment: You have to match the types in method call and method definition. they should be same or compatible. Try to give the valid data types would solve it if you still have problem then show us the data being passed in method call

Answer (score 3):

Here's your method declaration:

```
static void SaveData(string CustomerNumber, string CustomerName, 
                     string CustomerAddress, string CustomerRateType,
                     float Peak, float OffPeak, float Standard)
```

And here's your invocation:

```
SaveData(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, 
         CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, Standard, ref currentcustomer);
```

The compiler is telling you they don't match - and it looks like it's the last argument which is the problem, basically.

So you have three options:

- Remove the `ref currentcustomer` argument at the end of the call
- Change `SaveData` to add an appropriate parameter
- Change `SaveData` to return a customer *and* change the call:

  ```
  currentcustomer = SaveData(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, 
       CustomerAddress, CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, Standard);
  ```

I'd also suggest changing your parameter and local variable names to follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Jon, just when I was about to answer, you beat me to it Jon :P. I get tired of asking questions all the time :)

Answer (score 2):

`SaveData` takes 7 arguments, you are passing 1 extra argument.

There is another problem with your code, `SaveData` takes 4 `string` values and 3 `float` values while you are sending 4 `string[]` arrays and 3 `float[]` arrays:

```
    string[] CustomerNumber = new string[MAXCUSTOMERS];
    string[] CustomerName = new string[MAXCUSTOMERS];
    string[] CustomerAddress = new string[MAXCUSTOMERS];
    string[] CustomerRateType = new string[MAXCUSTOMERS];

    float[] Peak = new float[MAXCUSTOMERS];
    float[] OffPeak = new float[MAXCUSTOMERS];
    float[] Standard = new float[MAXCUSTOMERS];

    ...

    SaveData(CustomerNumber, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerRateType, Peak, OffPeak, Standard, ref currentcustomer);
```

You need to pass 1 element from each of those arrays like `CustomerNumber[i]` *where i = some array index*.

Answer (score 0):

your method **`SAVEDATA`**, it will only take 7 parameters and you are passing 8.

**The error message is self explanatory.**

Passing this many parameters wont be a good practice, make a poco class having types for all parameters and pass object of the class type