# No overload for method c#

Tags: c#, arguments, overloading

I have searched for a solution on numerious websites but I can't quite grasp the concept of overloading methods, at least not for this one as I can't see where I am going wrong with it. Whenever I try to call the method stated below I get this error - "No overload for method 'arrayCalculator' takes 0 arguments". I hope you will be able to help me with this. Thanks.

```
public class Calculations
{
    public static int[] arrayCalculator(object sender, EventArgs e, int m)
    {
        int i; 
        int[] result = new int[9];   
        int[] timesTable = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {                
            result[i] = m * timesTable[i];
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Calculation successful: " + m + " * " +  timesTable[i] + " = " + result[i] + "."); 
       }
       return result; // returns int result[]
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the calling code.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. How do you call it? This is the problem!

Comment: You probably type "arrayCalculator();" at calling, but you will need to provide the three parameters as well, as "arrayCalculator();" doesn't send any parameters to the method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No overload for method, takes 0 arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217681/no-overload-for-method-takes-0-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to call this function without any parameters. In your case, you only use the int parameter, so you should use the function below instead.

```
public class Calculations
{
    public static int[] arrayCalculator(int m)
    {
        int i; 
        int[] result = new int[9];   
        int[] timesTable = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {                result[i] = m * timesTable[i];
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Calculation successful: " + m + " * " +  timesTable[i] + " = " + result[i] + "."); 
       }
        return result; // returns int result[]
    }
}
```

Edit:

You are calling this function by `arrayCalculator();` Instead, pass in your parameter to the function so the function knows what do use in place of 'm' in your code.

Example:

Assume calculations is of type `Calculations`. Then you'd have

```
var mValue = 20;

var result = calculations.arrayCalculator(mValue);
```

Comment: Topic starter still needs to send 1 parameter to code you provided above, add-in how you call this method.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are calling your method as follow:

```
arrayCalculator();
```

Two ways to fix your problem.

1. Send the three needed parameters, to method that you want to call.
2. Modify your `arrayCalculator method`.

**1**

```
arrayCalculator(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
```

**2**

Modify your method so that zero parameters are required for calling it.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling it with no parameters.  Call it with 3 parameters.