# No overload for method takes 0 arguments for method

Tags: c#, overloading

Okay, I know there are thousands of questions like this but all the methods are different so how can i fix this problem
this is the method i want to call

```
private void GravityPlayer(GameTime gametime)
{

    while ((int)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds < 100)
    {
        KeyboardState keybState;
        keybState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keybState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) || keybState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            playerPos.Y = 100;
    }
}
```

this is the method from where i will call it from

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GravityPlayer();
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: GravityPlayer(gameTime); ?

Comment: It's pretty clear that GravityPlayer wants a GameTime but you aren't giving it one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No overload for method, takes 0 arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217681/no-overload-for-method-takes-0-arguments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is expecting a parameter of `GameTime`, just pass that in the call.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GravityPlayer(gameTime); //here
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```