# Alternatively upper- and lowercase words in a string

Tags: c#, string, uppercase

I use Visual Studio 2010 ver.

I have array strings [] = { "eat and go"};

I display it with foreach

I wanna convert strings like this : **EAT and GO**

Here my code:

```
Console.Write( myString.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("",myString].Skip(1)).ToLower()+ "\n");
```

But the output is : **Eat and go .** :D lol

Could you help me? I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Do you have some other cases or is it the only one?

Comment: Calling one string "strings" is really confusing. Good naming conventions helps a lot. In mean time check out `String.Split` and consider updating your post with new findings.

Comment: Cause I newbie in c#.. this is the only one

Comment: What does it mean " No overload for method 'ToUpper' takes 0 arguments " ?

Answer (score 3):

While `.ToUpper()` will convert a string to its upper case equivalent, calling `.First()` on a string object actually returns the first element of the string (since it's effectively a char[] under the hood). `First()` is actually exposed as a LINQ extension method and works on any collection type.

As with many string handling functions, there are a number of ways to handle it, and this is my approach. Obviously you'll need to validate `value` to ensure it's being given a long enough string.

```
using System.Text;

public string CapitalizeFirstAndLast(string value)
    {
        string[] words = value.Split(' '); // break into individual words

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        // Add the first word capitalized
        result.Append(words[0].ToUpper());

        // Add everything else
        for (int i = 1; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
            result.Append(words[i]);

        // Add the last word capitalized
        result.Append(words[words.Length - 1].ToUpper());

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe not related to my code sample, but OP did use it in their code (to retrieve the first *letter* instead of the first word)

Comment: Just remember that `someString.Split(char)` will take any `string` object you give it, look for a `char` value that matches, and return a `string[]` after it's been split up. Definitely the easiest way to break a string into words, but other ways exist too (such as regex) if you need to check more complex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always gonna be a 3 words `string`, the you can simply do it like this:

```
string[] mystring = {"eat and go", "fast and slow"};
foreach (var s in mystring)
{
    string[] toUpperLower = s.Split(' ');
    Console.Write(toUpperLower.First().ToUpper() + " " + toUpperLower[1].ToLower() +" " + toUpperLower.Last().ToUpper());
 }
```

Comment: I will try.. Btw, EAT and Go ,It is just example . I dont know how to convert upper-lower-upper string in array :)

Comment: @Nic Then go with Kyle solution. It seems to work with the strings with random lengths.

Comment: Could I ask you?   What does it mean " No overload for method 'ToUpper' takes 0 arguments " ?  And the result was : EATandGO . no space ( _ ) inside. Im newbie. Thank you .

Comment: @NicVia I edited my answer so the result would be "EAT and GO". and this link can help you with that error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217681/no-overload-for-method-takes-0-arguments

Comment: How about  Console.Write( myString.First().ToUpper() + myString.Last().ToUpper()); why it doesnt want to work .

Comment: @NicVia `mystring` as you created is an array string and `myString.First()` is the whole "eat and go" expression. so it won't work when you're trying to upper or lower it.

Comment: if I have mystring : { "eat and go" , "fast and slow" }
which part of code I change to display? it just can write "EAT and GO "only.. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continuously alternate, you can do the following:

```
private static string alternateCase( string phrase )
{
    String[] words = phrase.split(" ");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    //create a flag that keeps track of the case change
    book upperToggle = true;
    //loops through the words
    for(into i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        if(upperToggle)
            //converts to upper if flag is true
            words[i] = words[i].ToUpper();
        else
            //converts to lower if flag is false
            words[i] = words[i].ToLower();
        upperToggle = !upperToggle;
        //adds the words to the string builder
        builder.append(words[i]);
    }
    //returns the new string
   return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickie using ScriptCS:

```
scriptcs (ctrl-c to exit)

> var input = "Eat and go";
> var words = input.Split(' ');
> var result = string.Join(" ", words.Select((s, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? s.ToUpperInvariant() : s.ToLowerInvariant()));
> result
"EAT and GO"
```